# How do I permanitly disable Windows 10 Real-Time Protection?

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to permanently Disable Real-time Protection. All the solutions I have tried do not work. Can I accomplish this on the newest version of Windows 10?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/ionuttbara/windows-defender-remover ? Do not remove, just Disable. There's relevant option in the tool.

Comment: Is there a goal you're trying to accomplish that you believe disabling Windows Defender is the correct solution for? What is that goal? We may be able to give you a better solution that IS achievable.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the is a Corporate machine run by an IT department, no.

For regular consumers and regular consumer Windows 10 machines (and Windows 11), real time protection cannot be permanently disabled.

That is how Windows Defender and its structures work.

Microsoft updates normally find a way to re-enable real time protection - often at feature updates.

If you wish to acquire a good compliant Anti Virus, it will run instead of the Windows Defender scanner, but real time protection will still load and run.